# Sorting a LinkedList and implementing a find method

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a linked list class that provides a Node class.

I need to implement a sort class to sort out the contents of the linked list class in alphabetical order.

I also need to implement a find method so that the find method will return all the data of the index it matches to.

```
list.addFirst(new Contact1("John Harvey" ,6000, "jh@gmail.com"));
list.addFirst(new Contact1("Cris Irish",2000, "cI@gmail.com"));
"John Harvey" and "Cris Irish" are the names. I want to compare Cris Irish John Harvey and arrange them in alphabetical order.
```

Then I want to use the find method so that find("Cris Irish") returns :

"Cris Irish",2000, "cI@gmail.com"

And I wanna use a comparator to do it. But I have no idea how to pass it as an argument in the method.

This is my comparator class

```
public class ContactComparator implements Comparator<Contact1>{
@Override
 public int compare(Contact1 a, Contact1 b)
{
    return b.getName().charAt(0)-(a.getName().charAt(0));
}
}
```

I have a contact1 class that defines the contents if the linked list.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException; 


package project3;


import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException

public class LinkedList
{
private static Node first;
private int currentSize;
private static LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
/**
 * Constructs an empty linked list
 */
public LinkedList()
{
    first = null;
    currentSize=0;

}

/**
 * Returns the first element in the linked list.
 * @return the first element in the linked list
 */
public Object getFirst()
{
    return first;
}

/**
 * Removes the first element in the linked list.
 * @return the removed element
 */
public Object removeFirst()
{
    if (first == null) { throw new NoSuchElementException(); }
    Object element = first.data;
    first = first.next;
    currentSize--;
    return element;
}

/**
 * Adds an element to the front of the linked list.
 * @param the element to add
 */
public void addFirst(Object element)
{
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.data = element;
    newNode.next = first;
    first = newNode;
    currentSize++;
}

/**
 * A linked list node, holding the data (an object) and a pointer to
 * the next node in the list.
 */
class Node
{
    public Object data;
    public Node next;
    }


/** Reverses Contents in the linked List */  
public void reverse()   {           
    if (first ==null)   {return;}
    Node primary = first;
    Node current = primary;
    Node previous = null;
    while (current!= null)  {
        Node next = current.next;
        current.next= previous;
        previous = current;
        current = next;
    }
    first = previous;
}

/** Gives the size of the linked List*/
public void size()  {
    Node element = first;
    int elementIndex = 0;
    if (first == null)  {System.out.println(0);}
    else {
        while (element!= null){
        element = element.next;
        elementIndex++;}
        }
    System.out.println(elementIndex);
    }
/**  Helper method for get(int n) method */
private Node getNode(int n) {
    int index;
    Node element = first;
    for (index =0; index < n; index++)  {
        element = element.next;
    }
    return element;
}

/** Returns the nth element in the linked list */
public Object get(int n)    {
    return getNode(n).data;     
}

/** Sorts the linked List*/
public  void sort(Node node)        {

}



public Object findElement(Object element){
    }

public void print(Node node)    {
    if (node == null)   {node =first;}
while (node!= null) {
    System.out.println(node.data);
    node = node.next;
}
}

public class ContactComparator implements Comparator<Contact1>{
    @Override
     public int compare(Contact1 a, Contact1 b)
    {
        return b.getName().charAt(0)-(a.getName().charAt(0));
    }
}

public static void main (String [] args)    {
    list.addFirst(new Contact1("John Harvey" ,6000, "jh@gmail.com"));
    list.addFirst(new Contact1("Cris Irish",2000, "cI@gmail.com"));
    list.addFirst(new Contact1("Tom Jhonson",2400,"tj@gmail.com" ));
    System.out.println("Current List:");
    list.print(null);
    list.reverse();
    System.out.println("Reverse List: ");
    list.print(null);
    System.out.println("Size of the list");
    list.size();
    System.out.println("Current Size of the List");
    System.out.println(list.currentSize);   
    list.get(1);

}
}
```

Here's the contact class:

```
package project3;

public class Contact1 {

private String name;
private int number;
private String mail;

public Contact1(String n, int pn, String e){
    this.name= n;
    this.number = pn;
    this.mail =e;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return mail;
}
public void setEmail(String name) {
    this.mail = name;
}
public String toString(){
    return "Name: "+this.name+" "+" Number "+this.number+" Email: "     +this.mail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, you list has a natural order, so why don't you use a `TreeSet` instead of a list? In a set any entry must be unique and a tree set is ordered. Then your Contact1 class could implement `Comparable` and implement the `Comparator` itself.

Comment: Well this is a college project and the professor limited us to using Comparator or Comparable. We haven't done treeset yet.

Comment: Even so, making the `Contact1` class implement `Comparable` would get you around the need to pass the Comparator to the method. Another approach would be to define the comparater as a field in your LinkedList, as your list only contains elements of the same type, you can use the same Comparator. The best thing here would probably be to make the internal representation of your list a typed list of `Contact1`

Comment: `public  void sort(Node node)  {`
    `Node present = first;`
    `Node previous = null;`
    `for (present = first; present!=null; present = present.next) {`
     `previous = present;`
     `compare(previous.data, present.data);`
    `}`
    }`
And also modified the compare method. Still the list isn't sorted